# Problem of setting MaxReceivedMessageSize and MaxBufferSize in WCF application

Tags: wcf

I am implementing a large file streaming application using WCF.

I got a issue when I set the configuration for **MaxReceivedMessageSize** and **MaxBufferSize**. When these parameters are same system works fine. But when I chose different value it gives an error message,

> For TransferMode.Buffered, MaxReceivedMessageSize and MaxBufferSize must be the same value.

But I confused with the information in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx as follows,

> For example, suppose your service must receive files up to 4 GB in
>   size and store them on the local disk. Suppose also that your memory
>   is constrained in such a way that you can only buffer 64 KB of data at
>   a time. Then you would set the MaxReceivedMessageSize to 4 GB and
>   MaxBufferSize to 64 KB. Also, in your service implementation, you must
>   ensure that you read only from the incoming stream in 64-KB chunks and
>   do not read the next chunk before the previous one has been written to
>   disk and discarded from memory.to 4 GB and MaxBufferSize to 64 KB.
>   Also, in your service implementation, you must ensure that you read
>   only from the incoming stream in 64-KB chunks and do not read the next
>   chunk before the previous one has been written to disk and discarded
>   from memory.

Can anybody explain the reason of this matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the TransferMode. You should set it to streamed, if you want to use a different buffer size than message size.

transports support two modes of transferring messages in each direction:

- Buffered transfers hold the entire message in a memory buffer until the transfer is complete.
- Streamed transfers only buffer the message headers and expose the message body as a stream, from which smaller portions can be read at a time.